# How to create a vector of objects which inherit from the same base classes and have unique functions?

Tags: c++, function, inheritance, vector, virtual

I want to create vector of objects which inherit from the same base class but have their own functions, which are not in the base class (creating virtual function is not possible, because the classes which inherit take in different variables as parameters of a function).

Base class: Model

First class which inherits from Model class: Bus

```
void Bus::draw_model_bus(angle_x, angle_y, P_scene, V_scene, M_scene) const;
```

Second class which inherits from Model class: Grass

```
void Grass::draw_model_grass(P_scene, V_scene, M_scene) const;
```

... and I want to make it possible to call above functions on Bus and Grass objects which are stored in this one vector of models. `std::vector<Model*> models;` Code below doesn't work:

```
    models[0]->draw_model_bus(angle_x, angle_y, P_scene, V_scene, M_scene);
    models[1]->draw_model_grass(P_scene, V_scene, M_scene);
```

I wanted to initialize these objects like this:

```
    // Bus
    models.emplace_back(Bus("res/models/Bus.obj", "res/textures/Bus_tex.tga.png"));
    models[0]->read_model();
    
    // Grass
    models.emplace_back(Grass("res/models/grass.obj", "res/textures/grass.png"));
    models[1]->read_model();
```

How to make it possible to store these object like I described above?

Comment: To store pointers, you need to use `new`  however, I'd recommend a vector of `shared_ptr`

Comment: ^^^ even after that, your questionable choice of collection and desire to invoke derivation-specific non-virtual members will require some targeted `dynamic_pointer_cast` usage.

Comment: @ChrisMM then it is not possible to call draw_model_bus and draw_model_grass functions.

Comment: Not unless the base class defines them as virtual methods. Are you familiar with virtual methods, and how they work?

Comment: @WhozCraig  in your opinion, should I abandon this idea? I wanted to implement it like that, because these lines of code which initialize objects are called inside another classes function (called Scene), so I wanted to have these objects stored somewhere to access them in another function in Scene easily.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I know how they work, but it would be not possible to write it in a clean way, because these functions even if they could have the same name (draw_model), they would take in different parameters. If I wrote ``` virtual void draw_model(angle_x, angle_y, P_scene, V_scene, M_scene) = 0```  and ``` virtual void draw_model(P_scene, V_scene, M_scene) = 0```  in base class, I would have to implement these two in two derived classes, even if it is not needed.

Comment: That's abstract functions, not just a mere virtual function. Implement them in a base class, to throw an exception indicating that they're being called for the wrong type of an object.

Comment: I can't really make that call. It isn't uncommon that eventually you need class-specific operations on dynamic derivations held in a container. Normally something like a visitor pattern can patch that up. E.g. you visit all the nodes with a 'handler' callback, and that callback could, for example, invoke the proper `bus` vs `grass` vs `whatever` methods depending on the success/failure of dynamic pointer cast results. The real question is how much you find yourself doing direct derivation-specific ops vs virtual ops out of the base. If its nearly/all the time, the common base is questionable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid what you want to achieve is not possible in a simple way. That is because the C++ mechanisms you are trying to use were not designed to be used in such a way.

Inheritance - you would use it if:

- you want to reuse the interface, which seems not to be the case here, because you want different function names;
- or, you'd want to reuse the implementation, aka common code which is already present in the base class.

In order to workaround your problem with different parameters, you could encapsulate those into a wrapper object, which can be created either from the first or the second set. Something like this:

```
class Input {
public:
 Input(int angle_x, int angle_y, int P_scene, int V_scene, int M_scene);
 Input(int P_scene, int V_scene, int M_scene);
 ...
};


class Model {
public:
  virtual void draw(const Input& in);
  ...
};

class Bus: public Model {
public:
  void draw(const Input& in) override;
  ...
};

class Grass: public Model {
public:
  void draw(const Input& in) override;
  ...
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Model*> models;
    ...
    models[0]->draw(Input(angle_x, angle_y, P_scene, V_scene, M_scene));
    models[1]->draw(Input(P_scene, V_scene, M_scene));
}
```

Comment: How to access separate variables of in? in->angle_x and in.angle_x do not work.

Comment: @code_rushh where do you want to access them?

Comment: In function draw_model. Is there a need to create variables in class Input?

Comment: I assume by draw_model you mean draw. Yes, class Input may need to have some member variables called accordingly, to store the state. You'd have to make them public or provide public accessors to them...